# htaccess conditional rule based on url parts

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url like domain.com/category/
Somehow, Google has picked up domain.com/category/category/ which ends up somewhere else.
the "category" for the rule I would like to create will always be the same, so what I would like to do is find our if this matches and then strip either one.
The url will then go to the right place.

i.e. domain.com/category/category/ should end up like domain.com/category/ if /category/ matches the second /category/

Is this possible with a simple condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, possible with simple condition using the `\1` backreference:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/\1/
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$1/$3 [L,R=301]
```

Or you can just do it all in the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/\1/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Jon, testing this seems to work on urls without follow on, but the following still resolves to the same path / i.e. domain.com/category/category/differentcategory/ - doesnt change. Could there be another rule causing this to not work?

Comment: @Innate Maybe, this works for me in a blank htaccess file no matter what's after the 2 `/category/`'s (the `(.*)` captures that). Are you sure this rule is at the very top of all of your rules?